# spring batch: make transaction read only

Tags: spring-batch

In batch:chunk, set of records are being read, processed (value manipulated and modified) and then written to a XML. Once the chunk completes, it is trying to commit the modified data back to the database. But I do not want that to happen. Is there a way to set the transaction readonly? 
I tried to make the fetch method readonly, but it didnt work. I read that by default transaction commits after completion of a chunk. batch:transaction-attributes defined inside a batch:tasklet takes only propagation, timeout, isolation level values. But not readOnly.. 
Please suggest.

```
<batch:job id="job1">
    <batch:step id="step1">
        <batch:tasklet>
            <batch:chunk reader="itemReader" writer="itemWriter" processor="itemProcessor" 
                commit-interval="500">
            </batch:chunk>
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>
    <batch:listeners>
        <batch:listener ref="jobListener" />
    </batch:listeners>
</batch:job>
```

Itemreader:

```
public class XReader implements ItemReader {
@Autowired
private XRepository classDao;

private List lst = new ArrayList();
private int index= 0;

public Object read() throws Exception, UnexpectedInputException,     ParseException, NonTransientResourceException {
    if (lst.isEmpty()) {
           lst = classDao.findAll();
    } 
    if (index < lst.size()) {
        return lst.get(index++);
    } else return null;

}
}
```

Comment: What reader are you using?  You can't make the transaction itself read only because that would prevent the writing of the job's metadata.

Comment: Updated the reader class. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: why do you have a item writer if you don't want to update the records?

Comment: Then how to read the records from database?

Comment: I used a tasklet to read the records from database, then stored them in JobExecutionContext. In ItemReader,in @BeforeStep , the records are retrieved from Execution context. This works fine.  But I have a doubt here.. what happens when number of records is more, say millions of records.. how can this be handled?

Comment: Item writer is to write to an xml output.